# PHP \MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite can't delete _id.$oid Object

Tags: mongodb, php-7

I have a script removing Mongo records on PHP7 \MongoDB\Driver as this

```
$db = new \MongoDB\Driver\Manager(".......");
$bulk = new \MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite;
$bulk->delete(["_id":"5887e6fda69ca3797f74a4fd"], ['limit' => 1]);
$writeConcern = new \MongoDB\Driver\WriteConcern(\MongoDB\Driver\WriteConcern::MAJORITY, 1000);
$result = $db->executeBulkWrite('theplace.here', $bulk, $writeConcern);
```

I also tried

```
...
$bulk->delete(["_id.$oid":"5887e6fda69ca3797f74a4fd"], ['limit' => 1]);
...
```

This works for any field I send, it does delete... it just doesn't work when I want to remove an _id _id.$oid, like if it was ignoring without throwing errors.

Any help really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID when matching an _id with an ObjectId value. As strings and ObjectIds are not directly comparable:

```
$bulk->delete(
    ["_id"   => new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID("5887e6fda69ca3797f74a4fd")],
    ['limit' => 1]
);
```

Comment: If this answer helped you, please accept it. You can read how to do it here http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: This applies for all operations using `\MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite`. I had an `updateMany` which basically did nothing because I was providing the `_id` as a string instead of an `ObjectID`. I wish the docs pointed this out better.